# debian 8 server, не могу войти под root

Tags: debian

Всем привет!
Такая проблема, установили на pc debian 8 server, и не получается войти через ssh под root, но если войти в пользователя пк через ssh, а уже потом ввести "su" и пароль от root, то войти получается. Почему так и как это исправить ?

Comment: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` - найдите `PermitRootLogin without-password` и замените на `PermitRootLogin yes` перезапустите `su service ssh restart`

Answer (score 0):

Это стандартная мера безопасности, защита от брутфорса.

Исправить, точнее, испортить, можно, прописав `PermitRootLogin yes` в `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Но лучше всё же используйте `su` или `sudo`. Или хотя бы авторизуйтесь рутом по ключу, а не по паролю.